# How to set three different colors for mesh style?

Tags: plotting, customization

I want to assign different color for horizontal lines (x=0.25, x=0.5, x=0.75) in the 3D plot of $f(x,y)= x^2y$.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y
p1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), 
   MeshStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}, 
   Mesh -> {{{0.25}, {0.5}, {0.75}}}, PlotLabel -> "F(x,y)"]
```

The resulting graph is as follow,

[image]

As you can see the different colors hadn't applied and all three lines are red. I'm wondering how to change the color of lines to Red, Blue and Green respectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y
p1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
  , MeshFunctions -> (#1 &)
  , Mesh -> {
    {{0.25, {Red, Thick}}
     , {0.5, {Green, Thick}}
     , {0.75, {Blue, Thick}}}
    }
  , PlotLabel -> "F(x,y)"
  ]
```

[image]